# Return the top ten results from a range with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to add criteria to a formula to bring back the top ten most repeating values that match a criteria. So far I'm using...

=IFERROR(MODE(IF(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data,$C$1:C2,0)),Data)),"")

to get the top ten reoccurring numbers, then in the next column using

=COUNTIF(Data,C2) to show the number of times the number occurs in the range

How would I show how many times the number occurs in the range for just one criteria ignoring any blank cells in the range?[TOP TEN HELP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laduQ.png)

Comment: Pivot table has a top/bottom feature

Comment: The pivot is not an option, The criteria is a filter of the pivot and pulls in data, the case additional rows and values each having a set of values which when top 10 is set only shows the top 10 of each row if it is possible to use that to show another top ten then the pivot would work.

Comment: I attempted an aggregate formula but it did not bring back the desired results, maybe because of the blank cells. If there is a way to use aggregate 14,7 and have it ignor blanks that would be great.